# vb.net System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine to distinguish between user input and System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, speechsynthesizer

I'm working on a speech app that listens to a user, process the input and perform any actions if required, then provides output to the user.

I'm using the `System.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine` for listening to the user and the `System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer` to verbally output to the user.

I have the SPR listening continuously as I want to allow the user to interrupt the TTS  if the TTS is busy speaking but, obviously, the SPR is listening to the TTS whenever the TTS is speaking, triggering the process to find out what was said and trying to perform any actions.

I'm looking for some ideas on how to have the SPR determine whether it is hearing the user or the TTS when the user speaks while the TTS is speaking also.

**UPDATE** I may have found a solution.

I can use a public boolean `TtsSpeaking` that the TTS can set to `true` when it starts speaking, then set it to `false` when it completes.

During the `SpeechHypothesized` event of the SPR, It can check if `TtsSpeaking` is `true` then check the hypothesized text to see if it contains the words like:

- `stop` andalso `talking`
- `pause` andalso `talking`

then calls a method that will "tell" the TTS to either stop or pause its speaking.

Will try it out then update again.
Tnx

**UPDATE 2**

The solution mentioned above works. I also added a "safeguard" to prevent the SPR's `SpeechHypothesized` event from calling the `stop/pause talking` methods if it finds the above word combo in the hypothesized text if the user didn't say those words, but the TTS did:

The TTS exposes what it is going to say so, again, having the TTS set a public variable with what is going to say, the `SpeechHypothesized` event can check if the TTS spoke the qualifying word combo, and if not, assumes that the user spoke them and then call the `stop/pause` talking method.

Comment: Clearly you don't like the "listening continuously" mode.  So don't use it.

Comment: Just updated my question, last line. Basically it's a case of: when u speak to someone, you hear yourself speak but you continue to speak cause you know you are hearing yourself speak, but if the other person starts to speak before you finished, then you stop speaking. I want to simulate this behavior.

Comment: That works for a human, we are very good at distinguishing voices from multiple speakers.  Not for computers, SPR has no such capability.  It is only as smart as the programmer that uses it.